# Как выровнять таблицу по центру?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

HTML:

```
<table class="table table-sm table">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
            <tr>
                <th><h5>Predictions</h5></th>
                <th><h5>Probability value</h5></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>Both to score (yes)</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.both_score_yes }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Both to score (no)</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.both_score_no }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Over 2.5</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.over_25 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Under 2.5</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.under_25 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>1X</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.1x_team1 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>X2</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.x2_team2 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ predictions.name_team1 }} score</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.score_yes_team1 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ predictions.name_team2 }} score</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.score_yes_team2 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ predictions.name_team1 }} over 2.5</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.ind_total_over_25_team1 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ predictions.name_team1 }} under 2.5</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.ind_total_under_25_team1 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ predictions.name_team2 }} over 2.5</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.ind_total_over_25_team2 }}</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>{{ predictions.name_team2 }} under 2.5</th>
                <td>{{ predictions.ind_total_under_25_team2 }}</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

CSS:

```
.table {
    width: 500px;
    margin: 0;
}

.table td {
    text-align: center;
}
```

Почему то смещается влево

Как выровнять чтобы была по центру ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

почти так, только допиши здесь "margin: 0 auto;"

Comment: Спасибо! Сработало